# Implementing a custom audio HAL in android

Tags: android, audio, android-audiorecord, audio-player, hal

How to implementing a custom audio HAL in android?
What are the different approaches to implement the audio HAL in android Ex. TinyHAL, UCM etc. I am looking for various approaches to suite my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First and the most important question you should ask yourself is if you really need to implement your own HAL.

Secondly, there is a mandatory reading - [Audio Architecture in Android](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/).

Next, check the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/) e.g. for one of the Nexus devices, this can be treated as a reference design.

After lots of code writing and lots of debugging pass CTS testsuit, to make sure you are compliant with the Android OS.